# Как дождаться разблокировки мьютекса потока, запущенного сигналом Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, c++11

Есть такой код

```
for (;;) {
    //...
    _mutex.unlock();
    f();
    _mutex.lock();
    //...
}
```

Функция `f()` вызывает сигнал Qt для перерисовки, обработка которого, как я понимаю происходит в новом неизвестном мне потоке, и он не всегда успевает захватить мьютекс и `_mutex.lock` из кода выше срабатывает раньше. Как я могу заставить `_mutex.lock` выполниться не раньше, чем отработает обработка сигнала? Я использую потоки C++11.

Comment: Без раскрытия "отработает обработка сигнала" вряд ли возможно что-то подсказать. Что за обработка? Выдаёт ли какой сигнал по окончанию своей работы? А так вообще любые работы по перерисовке чего-либо в Qt всегда выполняются в главном или иначе сказать GUI-потоке.

Comment: Как вариант: выделить метод(ы). В конце `f()` генерировать сигнал типа drawingFinished() и повесить на него слот с `lock(); …`

Answer (score 1):

Вы что-то делаете не правильно, блокировать/разблокировать мутекс должны потоки выполняющие работу с разделяемым ресурсом. То есть, раз потоки "знают" о ресурсе, то они обязаны "знать" и о мутексе. Это означает, что вам нужно "протянуть" мутекс внутрь `f()`. Либо выбрать другую схему синхронизации, например на сообщениях, которыми, кстати, и являются сигналы Qt.

Comment: Была причина, по которой обновление окна пришлось делать через сигнал обновления, а не напрямую, я её не помню но могу поискать. Из-за того что я обновление не вызываю напрямую, поток который создаётся для обновления окна, не всегда успевает завладеть мьютексом раньше, чем `_mutex.lock()` из кода выше. Но у этого потока есть доступ к этому мьютексу и он его лочит, но не всегда первым. После обновления VS и Qt он не всегда успевает первым его заблокировать, только в ~70% случаев.

Comment: @Ufx По сути вы хотите чтобы они работали синхронно. Поэтому либо выполняйте все в одном потоке, либо меняйте логику. Простое наличие мутекса не создает паралельность, прежде всего сама логика должна быть таковой.

Comment: Насколько я понял вызов сигнала update вызывает функцию отрисовки в каком-то новом потоке. Но если саму функцию отрисовки вызвать в том же потоке, это по каким-то, не помню каким причинам, не работает, или работает не так как надо. То есть у меня складывается такая ситуация - вызываю сигнал, который создаёт некий поток, и мне надо сделать дожидание завершения того нового потока, чтобы код продолжил выполняться.

Comment: @Ufx Распишите вопрос подробнее, чтобы было понятно кто кого вызывает и ждет, что конкретно не работает.

Comment: А что же помешало использовать Qt-потоки? К тому же `QThread` наследуется от `QObject` и вы сможете непосредственно использовать сигналы-слоты.

Comment: @aleks-andr Я использую std::thread потоки в ядре проекта, чтобы оно не зависило от фреймворка.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778737/qt-gui-doesnt-work-with-stdthread-as-i-expect сейчас создал более подробный вопрос, это то с чего я начинал. Потом кто-то мне подсказал использовать обновление через сигналы, с ними не падало и работало в нужном порядке, пока я не обновил VS и Qt.